# Multiple audio sources to monitoring speakers

Tags: mixing, speakers, hardware, mixer

I bought a mixer (Alesis MultiMix 4) thinking I would be able to connect multiple stereo audio sources (jack or mini jack) , adjust their level which each knob and output everything on a pair of monitoring speakers. For instance, the output of the phono preamp + computer + bluetooth receiver.

The mixer fails to complete this task because the 2 of the 4 inputs are mono and not stereo (which I foolishly thought they were).

So, is there any (cheap if possible) piece of hardware which would allow me to have multiple stereo audio sources plugged in the monitoring speakers and control their volume independently?

Edit:

I know there are other mixers out there such as Soundlab Micro Mixer, but I was wondering if there was another piece of kit which would do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition you are looking for a mixer.  A mixer is a device that takes multiple inputs and adjusts the levels in to one output.  I suppose in theory, you may be able to make a passive circuit that could variably attenuate the signal and combine them while preventing back feed, but that would still be a simple passive mixer and might well have sound quality issues.

Comment: Thanks! Any particular model/brand to recommend? All the stuff I find seems to have either stuff I don't need or doesn't do what I want (besides the Soundlab Micro Mixer, which would still need a bunch of Jack/Jack to female mini jack for me to plug in external stereo sources (phone, computer, etc.).

Comment: In case someone else is looking for this, the best I could find was the Rolls MX 41b. Otherwise there's a DIY solution http://www.instructables.com/id/Altoids-Tin-18-Stereo-Mixer/